# Extract day, month, year from a YYYY-DD-MM string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I am finding the best solution for extracting day, month, year from string with `YYYY-DD-MM` in Javascript:

Extract from:

`2019-25-01`

To object:

`{ day: 25, month: 01, year: 2019 }`

What is the best way to do it. Thank in advance!

Comment: Surely you have tried some coding already to solve this problem.  Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Cid: This is not one of the supported formats for `Date.parse`; so, not a dupe (as it requires further steps).

Comment: @Amadan ah, true, thanks for pointing me that. I didn't notice the date is in a stupid format, un-sortable and so on.

Comment: @Cid: Stupid or not, it's official in [three countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian,_year-day-month_(YDM)).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could split, destructure and return a new object.

```js
const getDate = string => (([year, day, month]) => ({ day, month, year }))(string.split('-'));

console.log(getDate('2019-25-01'));
```

Comment: This is elegant.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use a regular expression to `match` each number sequence, map the array of matched strings to numbers, destructure into variables, then create an object from it:

```js
const [year, day, month] = '2019-25-01'
  .match(/\d+/g)
  .map(Number);
const obj = { day, month, year };
console.log(obj);
```

Note that numbers cannot have leading zeros. If you want the month to have a leading zero, use a string instead (just remove the `.map(Number)`).

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty short and fast solution that will only work for that format and in ES6

```js
function getJsonDate(text) {
  var {0: year, 1: day, 2: month } = text.split("-");
  return { day, month, year};
}
console.log(getJsonDate("2019-25-1"));
```

If you need the fields to be numbers then you can add a map, like so:

```js
function toNumber(text) {
  text = text - 0;
  return isNaN(text) ? 0 : text;
}
function getJsonDate(text) {
  var {0: year, 1: day, 2: month } = text.split("-").map(toNumber);
  return { day, month, year};
}
console.log(getJsonDate("2019-25-1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split()`to do it

```js
var value = "2019-25-01";
var year = value.substring(0,4);
var day = value.substring(5,7);
var month = value.substring(8,10);
var str = "{day:" + day + ",month:" + month + ",year:" + year + "}";
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Hmm this expect a specific format. "2019-1-2" won't work (you didn't split by the way)

Comment: yeah,but I do not know if it matches the pattern `YYYY-DD-MM` that the OP mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Use [.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

```js
let date = "2019-25-01"
let dateArr = date.split('-')
let obj = {
  day: dateArr[1],
  month: dateArr[2],
  year: dateArr[0]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You can save some operation storing the split in an array before building the object

Comment: @Cid Thanks! I totally forgot that. Here I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For JSON like structure

```
d="2019-25-01";
x=d.split("-");
json="{ day: "+x[1]+", month: "+x[2]+", year: "+x[0]+" }";
>>"{ day: 25, month: 01, year: 2019 }"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have one approach that don't need to do the mapping `str -> array -> object`, it will convert the `string` directly to `object` and can be used also for a more generalized date with time. It is based on the `replacement` function that can be used on [String::replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const dateStr1 = "2019-25-01";
const dateMap1 = ["year", "day", "month"];
const dateStr2 = "2019-25-01 17:07:56";
const dateMap2 = ["year", "day", "month", "hour", "minute", "second"];

const splitDate = (str, map) =>
{
    let obj = {}, i = 0;
    str.replace(/\d+/g, (match) => obj[[map[i++] || i - 1]] = match);

    return obj;
}

console.log(splitDate(dateStr1, dateMap1));
console.log(splitDate(dateStr2, dateMap2));
```

Another way that is strictly related to your date format could be next one:

```js
const strDate = "2019-25-01";

const splitDate = (str) =>
{
    let [date, year, day, month] = str.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/);
    return {year, month, day};
}

console.log(splitDate(strDate));
```